# How to set the linkedcell property of a checkbox on a userform to a cell on a worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, checkbox

I have a worksheet that contains cost codes. After the columns that define the cost codes I have multiple columns of data for jobs that will get a true or false value as to whether that cost code applies to the job identified by that column.

I have a userform that contains 700+ Checkboxes that I want to link dynamically to the columns of data on a job by job basis. After querying the user for information, we determine which column of data is for a specific job which gets stored in the variable ACTUALCOLUMN.

When I load and initalize the userform, I loop through all controls on the userform that are checkboxes. The checkbox name has a matching entry in the cost code worksheet data in column P (static). I can query what row has the matching cost code name, but when I try to link the checkbox to a cell on a column of the same row, I get a run time error 438 "Object doesn't support this property or method."

I have tried multiple ways writing the code around the with checkbox linked cell routines, none seem to be working for me.

Intent is for user to select checkboxes for all cost codes that apply on the form, and populate the linked cell in the cost code worksheet with a corresponding value which I assume is a true or false.

is it possible to link the existing checkbox on a userform to a sheet? All the examples that I could find were more related to checkboxes on the actual work sheet and linking to cells on that same worksheet.

```
Dim wb as Workbook
Dim ws as Worksheet
Dim CheckboxRange as Range
Dim ChkBox as MSForms.control
Dim EnableChkBoxes as Boolean
set wb = thisworkbook
set ws11 = wb.sheets("COST CODES")

'Userform where all the checkboxes are is called ActivateCC - There are a total of 700+ checkboxes within 'the form on multi-sheet tabs.

For Each ChkBox In ActivateCC.Controls
        If TypeName(ChkBox) = "CheckBox" Then
            Set ChkBoxRange = ws11.Range("P:P").Find(What:=ChkBox.Name, LookIn:=xlValues)
            If Not ChkBoxRange Is Nothing Then
                If EnableChkBoxes = True Then
                    If ws11.Cells(ChkBoxRange.Row, 17).Value = "Yes" Then ChkBox.Enabled = True Else ChkBox.Enabled = False  'Checks an administrator column for valid CC's
                End If
                With ChkBox
                    .LinkedCell = ws11.Cells(ChkBoxRange.Row, ACTUALCOLUMN).Address  '<---ERROR HERE
                End With
            End If
        End If
Next ChkBox
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two issues here:

1. You need to use the `ControlSource` property (not `LinkedCell`)
2. You should specify the worksheet too, otherwise the cb will be linked to whatever sheet is active when you assign the address (use `ws11.Cells(ChkBoxRange.Row, ACTUALCOLUMN).Address(0,0,,1)`

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you!  This worked perfectly.  I was looking the the property fields for MSForms.controls and I saw the ControlSource property, so I had tried this, but it would not work without the qualifiers you note in point #2.  My only other solution by brute force was to dim a range variable for every checkbox, check the value in the worksheet it was to pair up with to set the initial value for the checkbox, and then have a sub for every checkbox change event to check the checkbox value and write that to the worksheet. You just saved me literally 8000 lines of code.